# Help with a rewrite rule that isn't working

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm using the following rewrite rule, but I can't get it to work:

```
RewriteRule  ^rates/([a-z]+)\.php$  /rates.php?c_user_action=view_type&vehicle_type=$1  [QSA,L,NC]
```

The URL I'm using is `http://www.example.com/rates/motorhomes.php`

At the moment it's just going to /rates.php without a query string.

The weird this is if I change the rewrite expression to `^rates-([a-z]+)\.php$` and the URL to `http://www.example.com/rates-motorhomes.php` then it works.

I've used something similar on other sites/servers without any issue, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. This server is running Apache 2.2.

I know mod_rewrite is working, because the following 2 rules work:

```
RewriteRule  ^blah([a-z]+)\.php$  /rates.php?test=$1  [L]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)\.[\d]+\.(css|js)$  $1.$2  [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s probably [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) that’s causing this behavior, mapping `/rates/motorhomes.php` to `/rates.php/motorhomes.php` before passing the request through to mod_rewrite. Try to disable it:

```
Options -MultiViews
```